# xCode install error - Failed to load info.plist from GoogleUtilities.framework

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, admob, cordova-ios

I have this cordova (ionic) project which runs fine on devices. I wanted to add a Widget extension (iOS 14 widgets) to the project, when I started getting errors about Google Ad Mob framework missing, so I manually added them (files on the image below). However this is not isolated to widget extension, the issue is present every time another target is added to xCode.

[image: List of included frameworks]

Now, the app builds successfully, however I get an install error:

On Simulator:

```
Could not install at this time.
Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path /Users/[user]/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/[device-code]/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.aGSOBa/extracted/Busko.app/Frameworks/GoogleUtilities.framework;
Extra info about Info.plist: Couldn't stat /Users/[user]/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/[device-code]/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.aGSOBa/extracted/Busko.app/Frameworks/GoogleUtilities.framework/Info.plist: No such file or directory
```

On actual device:

```
Unable to install "Busko"
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402653103
--
Could not inspect the application package.
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402653103
User Info: {
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 282703;
    MobileDeviceErrorCode = "(0xE8000051)";
    "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
    0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000011d3f093f DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 220
    1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000011d42f124 __90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke + 155
    2   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000100c0fb53 DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 71
    3   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000011d42ee65 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] + 1440
    4   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x000000011d29fd28 __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.292 + 3513
    5   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000100d3e2ba __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 7
    6   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000100d3fedc __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 1191
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6dc466c4 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6dc47658 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6dc4cc44 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 597
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6dc4d5d6 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 363
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6dc56c09 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 596
    12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff6dea1a3d _pthread_wqthread + 290
    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff6dea0b77 start_wqthread + 15
);
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 10.15.6 (Build 19G2021)
Xcode 12.0 (17219)
```

Some additional info:

```
I am using latest cordova-plugin-admob-plus for admob. 
Cordova version: 6.1.1
xCode version: 12
iOS version: 14.0
```

I tried everything I could find Google-ing and nothing seemed to work. What am I missing?

Comment: I have seen a similar issue when using Cocoapods, the framework simply did not have an info.plist. Full cleanout and pod install, and the plist showed up allowing install to work.